# Cannot read property '_externalStream' of null

Tags: node.js, server

I need help!! I dont know why i catch this error.

```
_http_server.js:326
socket.on('drain', socketOnDrain);
^
TypeError: Cannot read property '_externalStream' of null
at Server.connectionListener (_http_server.js:331:32)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Object.onconnection (net.js:1427:8)
at onconnection (cluster.js:646:26)
at Worker.onmessage (cluster.js:527:9)
at process.<anonymous> (cluster.js:710:8)
at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
at process.emit (events.js:172:7)
at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:685:10)
```

please explain me how solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not find why this happened, but i know it linked with large memory consumption. So i run several apps and add nginx balancing. 
After error never repeated.